# Seeking advice on how to make camera movement for a over the shoulder camera in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

Okay so i have not gotten that far with my camera controller since i find it quit hard to actully come up with something that works, as you can see i am getting the input from my mouse and give the values to my mouseDelta variable. Everything helps!

This is the edit which i talked about in the comments.

```
using UnityEngine.InputSystem;
using UnityEngine;

public class CameraController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public InputActionAsset cameraInputs;
    private InputActionMap cameraMap;
    private InputAction lookAction;

    public float sensitivity = 10f;

    public Transform player;

    private Vector2 lookInput;

    public Vector3 defaultCameraPosition;
    private Vector3 initialOffset;
    private void Awake()
    {
        cameraMap = cameraInputs.FindActionMap("CameraMap");
        lookAction = cameraMap.FindAction("Look");
        lookAction.performed += OnLookPerformed;
    }

    private void Start()
    {
        transform.position = defaultCameraPosition;

        if (player == null)
        {
            initialOffset = transform.position - player.position;

            transform.LookAt(player.position);
        }

        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
        Cursor.visible = false;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        Vector3 mouseDelta = new Vector3(-lookInput.y, lookInput.x, 0f) * sensitivity * Time.deltaTime;
    }

    private void LateUpdate()
    {
        RotateCamera();
    }

    private void OnEnable()
    {
        cameraMap.Enable();
    }

    private void OnDisable()
    {
        cameraMap.Disable();
    }

    private void OnLookPerformed(InputAction.CallbackContext context)
    {
        lookInput = context.ReadValue<Vector2>();
    }

    private void RotateCamera()
    {
        float yaw = lookInput.x * sensitivity * Time.deltaTime;
        float pitch = -lookInput.y * sensitivity * Time.deltaTime;

        player.Rotate(0f, yaw, 0f, Space.World);

        Vector3 currentRotation = player.transform.localEulerAngles;
        float newPitch = currentRotation.x + pitch;

        float maxPitch = 80f;
        newPitch = Mathf.Clamp(newPitch, -maxPitch, maxPitch);

        player.transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(newPitch, currentRotation.y, currentRotation.z);

        transform.LookAt(player.position);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show some screen shots

Comment: @Obscure021 okay so i am on a trip but i can try to explain my setup. 

I have the camera as a child of my player object, the player object has a character controller and movement script. Then on the camera there is just the camera controller. Feel free to ask for more information if needed!

Comment: So whats wrong with it?

Comment: @BugFinder i need help devloping the camera movement to clarify!

Comment: This isnt a code writing service.  So, you need to explain exactly whats wrong with it and what you did to try fix it

Comment: @BugFinder so this is what i done so far, i added the new code to the edit of the question. But i run in to the problem when moving the mouse up and down the player rotates on up and down on the x axel which it should not do.